# D3-Updating line chart dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am new to d3, working on updating the line chart dynamically based on interval, i want the old data to be moveout/exit and update with new data, i am stuck at a position where i can see new data joins the chart but old data is not moving out/exiting. Can someone please help me out on this issue, any help is much appreciated.

Copied from [d3noob's`link`](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/6bd13f974d6516f3e491) with little variation of injecting data to chart

Plunker [`link`](https://plnkr.co/edit/XbiLytPFt3xmURAyNu7A?p=preview)

Also i am trying to add the circles for each point, currently the single circle is added on top of Y-axis for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

While checking [d3noob's link](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/6bd13f974d6516f3e491) I realized that he's using 2 datasets as `data.csv` and `data-alt.csv`. During the second run of `updateData` function it always gets `data-alt.csv`

So, in order to answer your question,

1. First, you need to get your data generation logic correct. Since you are generating random numbers you need to make sure your `randomPoints()` function generates proper dates that are understandable to D3
2. Then bind the randomly generated dataset to your `data` variable.
3. Finally, clear your `data` variable in every run of `updateData` function.

I have made a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SGzuJaAjcmViIVUoNnV1) for you. Let me know if you need more explanation on this.

Hope this helps :)